# How can I access a liferay instance in plain java?

Tags: java, http, connection, liferay, liferay-6

I have a java clasa (not a hook or portlet or anything like that, just plain java) that needs to use Liferay's API to update its lucene index. I've found the methods to do what I need to do, but I still don't know how to connect to my instance of liferay to make sure that things actually go into my search engine. Is there an easy way to open a connection to liferay and still use the api? I'd rather not use a remote connection since that seems to limit which methods I can access, but honestly I'll be happy with anything that works.

Also, (and this is probably obvious from my question), I'm very new at any kind of programming that involves using a connection, so if you are nice enough to respond, could you explain it to me like I'm stupid? Thanks!

Comment: Please add some details like 1) do you need to update Liferay's Lucene index? 2) which API you are interested in? 3) Does your Java class 'have to' run as independent program or it can run within Liferay container?

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you want to access some liferay methods which are not exposed as Remote API then:

1. you can create your own plugin
2. create methods which would use liferay's methods in your plugin, like a wrapper around liferay's methods.
3. then expose your custom methods as web-service for accessing remotely
4. This way you can build a web-service client to access liferay's API external to liferay

Ofcourse this is assuming you can deploy a plugin to the liferay server.

If you can provide more information as to what you intend to do, may be a usecase then we can provide some other alternative.

Hope this helps.